# Do synthesized properties in objective-c automatically trigger didChangeObjectForKey:?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've tried searching for this several times, but nowhere seems to have an definite answer.

If I have a synthesized property on my class (call it ClassA), can I observe it using KVO and get the results I would expect?

For example, in ClassA.h I have:

```
@property myProperty;
```

In ClassA.m I have:

```
@synthesize myProperty;
```

In another class, I observe the property:

```
[instanceOfClassA addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"myProperty"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:nil];
```

I don't implement any custom getter or setter for the property, it is using whatever the default implementation is. (I know I can always implement custom getters/setters and call willSetValueforKey: an didSetValueForKey: myself)

Comment: Sadly, it seems I ask difficult questions :) I still haven't found any documentation about this one yet :(

Comment: The problem on this one is that I've observed the behavior "in the wild" but it could just be an non-intended side effect subject to change in future SDK updates since there's no documentation about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will!!!

But you need to use... `self.property`.

`_property` bypasses KVC.

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere that verifies this, or is it just observed behavior?

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1

Comment: Even non-synthesized properties will. KVO uses class-isa swizzling for that, it's not "manually" implemented.